# Can I 'enable' js if I embed the 'real' page inside an amp-iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, iframe, amp-html

I'm trying to enable AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) on a JavaScript dependent page but AMP disallows js. Has anyone had any luck embedding pages with js in amp-iframes? And is this hacky enough that it might have negative SEO implications, perhaps, I'm afraid, quietly in the future? Or is it a super clever (and safe) thing that nobody does for some weird reason? I suspect it is a futile exercise but for the sake of the SEO I am tempted.

What I've learnt so far is that the `amp-iframe` source (at least) needs to be ssl enabled and it should not be same origin. So one would just need to put it somewhere else. I get that they may not want people doing this but I find it annoying cause my js is finally starting to be well behaved and I think it's unfair that a fast page can't get amp-related SEO points for being fast. Perhaps I'm missing something?

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/amp_replacements.html

Comment: please don't encourage de-standardization by corporate juggernauts by using AMP.

Comment: in short: you can't. Only pre-approved popular friends of AMP get to run their JS on AMP pages, everyone else gets a 2nd-class UX. Sadly, I am not even making this up.

Comment: Re: destandardization, true, not to mention all the extra work it would require. Re: js, good to know, thanks.