# AMP how to include javascript in page and apply functions from this script

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I've been trying to include a javascript file in AMP page but it fails each time i tried

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100px" 
                        layout="responsive" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
                        src="https://laraflat.000webhostapp.com/public/js/index2.js">

</amp-iframe>
```

but it fails to load the functions inside this script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Javascript in AMP Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748634/add-javascript-in-amp-pages)

Comment: i applied that answer but it didn't help

Comment: That's because the answer is "you can't do that."   Read the [spec](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#html-tags) :  "AMP HTML uses a set of contributed but centrally managed and hosted custom elements to implement advanced functionality such as image galleries that might be found in an AMP HTML document. While it does allow styling the document using custom CSS, **it does not allow author written JavaScript** beyond what is provided through the custom elements to reach its performance goals."

Comment: but the documentation also says that i can add javascript through using amp-iframe

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248005/can-i-enable-js-if-i-embed-the-real-page-inside-an-amp-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMP Prohibits the use of external javascript libraries. You can only make use of the native AMP component's script.

> JavaScript is powerful, it can modify just about every aspect of the
>   page, but it can also block DOM construction and delay page rendering
>   (see also Adding interactivity with JavaScript). To keep JavaScript
>   from delaying page rendering, AMP allows only asynchronous JavaScript.

For more information visit [here](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-how/)